# Why do I get a different behavior of the scp command in csh and bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scp, csh

Why do I get a different behavior of the scp command in csh and bash?

Same command is working in csh shell, but it not working in bash shell.

Please can anybody help?

---

```
bash-3.2$  csh
Linux-007% scp root@1.2.3.4:/{/root/install.log} /
install.log 100% 98KB 97.6KB/s 00:00
Linux-007%  which scp
/usr/bin/scp
```

---

```
Linux-007% bash
bash-3.2$  scp root@1.2.3.4:/{/root/install.log} /
scp: /{/root/install.log}: No such file or directory
bash-3.2$ which scp
/usr/bin/scp
```

Answer (score 2):

`scp` isn't the issue.  The problem is in the way the two shells handle curly braces.

```
csh% echo root@1.2.3.4:/{/root/install.log}
root@1.2.3.4://root/install.log

bash$ echo root@1.2.3.4:/{/root/install.log}
root@1.2.3.4:/{/root/install.log}
```

Why do you want the curly braces anyway?

Comment: yes, I want to copy multiple file.

Comment: The command you showed us only copies one file.  But if you want the braces to be interpreted on the remote system, put single quotes around the argument: `scp 'root@1.2.3.4:/{/root/install.log}' /`.

Comment: same problem
bash-3.2$  scp root@1.2.3.4:/'{/root/install.log}' /
root@12.3.4's password:
scp: /{/root/install.log}: No such file or directory

Comment: Then drop the braces.  If you're copying a single file, as you seem to be trying to do in your example, don't use braces.  If you really need to copy multiple files, use braces and commas, and quote them: `scp root@1.2.3.4:{this_file,that_file}' /`